# node npm install -g bower FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 on Win7

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, fatal-error, bower

Windows 7 Enterprise, Git and Node installed.
When I try to

```
    npm install -g bower
```

in command prompt (as administrator or user) on fresh node js install (x86 and x64), it sits there for 20 minutes and its memory usage slowly climbs up to 2GB of RAM. After 20 minutes it crashes with

```
    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory.
```

Any ideas about how to install bower globally?

UPDATE: It looks like npm fails to install any package globally (yeoman, grunt). Clearing cache, installing and reinstalling different node js versions or package version doesn't help.
I get a bunch of ENOENT and EPERM errors if I don't run

```
    npm rm -g bower
    npm cache clean
```

first. I think the part of the problem could be that my Windows profile is stored on unix server and the path length to my AppData/Roaming is about 100 characters long.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` and then `npm install bower`

Comment: `npm install bower` successfully finished with a warning `WARN prefer global`, but `npm install -g bower` still can't complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: admins changed the windows policy group for my profile, so that AppData is kept on local machine instead of remote server location and it fixed my problem. I can install any package globally now without any issues.